# Is it possible to start new inventory by one product category in openerp v8 like odoo 10

Tags: odoo, categories, odoo-8, odoo-10, article

I need to find some ways to create a new inventory by one product category 
It's easy to do it in odoo v10.0 but in version 8.0 it's quite impossible

ther's some images shows the user interface of both in odoo 8 and odoo 10 
[image: odoo v 8]
[image: odoo v 10]
Can you help to find somehow to do it